# iphone Development

Tags: iphone

How will you test an iPhone application without the iPhone being available?

Answer (score 5):

[The SDK](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/program/download.html) comes with a simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Of course the simulator doesn't really provide true feedback and it is most advised to do most of the testing on a real iPhone or an iPod if you don't own one, you could possibly use some beta testing program and publish your app there, using ad-hoc provisioning and adding UDID's according to requests. You could try "Mechanical Turk".

Comment: 'True feedback'?  About the only thing it doesn't simulate is multi-touch events.  Other than that, I'd say it's pretty damn good.  I developed an 8000 line app on the simulator, and when I got my dev cert for the device, it worked pretty much without modification..

Answer (score 0):

An iPhone application can be tested (to an extent) using simulators, it is included within iOS SDK. An iPhone application can run on simulators only if you have source code available with you, but cannot run iPhone builds (IPAfiles) directly on simulators.

The simulators have following limitations with reference to testing purposes
1. Accelerometer,
2. Telephony,
3. GPS,
4. Only up to two figure gestures can be simulated,
5. Hardware and memory, as simulators use the MAC hardware and memory etc.
So ideally testing on real device is more reliable rather than using simulators.